# Compare Vs2010 files while offline

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, offline

I want to compare 2 files that reside on my local disk while offline from TFS.  I appears that while offline, there is no functionality to do that compare.  Is there a good tool to file comparisons and hopefully a merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `WinMerge tool`

link : http://winmerge.org/?lang=fr

This tool can be integrated or not in your Visual Studio, on Source Control

Answer (score 0):

My favourite tool for doing this is [DiffMerge](http://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).